# Basic C++ Program ending prematurely

Tags: c++

I'm writing a simple program that takes an a series of integers, store them in a vector, and prints out the sum of 'x' number of ints in the vector. However the compiler seems to skip over my program after printing "how many integers would you like to add together?" after printing 0 to the screen.

```
std::vector<int>values;
int v = 0;
int it = 0;
int sum = 0;

int main() {

    std::cout << "Enter values" << std::endl;

    while (std::cin >> v) {
         values.push_back(v);
    }

    std::cout << "how many integers would you like to add together?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> it;

    for (int i = 0; i <= it - 1; ++i) {
         sum += values[i];
    }

    std::cout<<sum;
}
```

Comment: What do you enter, to stop the `while (std::cin >> v)` loop? If you enter EOF character, then `std::cin` is in an end-of-file state, and doesn't read any more input.

Comment: How did you stop inputting values at your while loop? It looks like `std::cin` is still in fail state when you're trying to enter `it`.

Comment: Usually, the idiomatic way of writing `i <= it - 1` is `i < it`.

Comment: I was just entering non-integer inputs to cause the while (std::cin >> v) to fail and exit the loop. It is working after terminating with ctr-z and adding a std::cin.clear() after the loop.

Comment: @Cook915 If you solved your own problem, you can post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to exit from the first `while` loop, you must have triggered end-of-file condition on `cin` (e.g. by pressing Ctrl+D with some shells). By the time `std::cin >> it` is reached, the stream is still in end-of-file state, so the read operation fails and `it` retains its value of zero.

Comment: You can also break the `while` loop by inputing anything that can't be extracted as a `double` like `"done"`. It's may just be in a failed state and not an EoF state.

Comment: I was using the failed state of cin to exit the loop. Using and EoF char and clearing cin seemed to solve the issue